# ¿Saben porque no me instala el chatterbot?

Tags: python, pip

al querer instalar el chatterbot mediante el CMD, me sale esté error, al principio sugería actualizar el pip (cosa que hice), pero ahora me sale un error distinto, adjunto imagen
**[image: bot]**

Answer (score 1):

Este error se genera debido a que en tu sistema no cuentas con una dependencia para la instalación, según leo es Visual Studio C++ 14.0.

**Solución:**

Si vas a [este enlace](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/downloads/) puedes descargar el instalador de Visual Studio, este sirve para instalar todos los paquetes que pone a dispocición Microsoft (con respecto a Visual Studio).

La dependencia en especifico que ocupas es Visual Studio C++, para instalarla debes de hacer lo siguiente en el instalador:

- Modficar la versión Community, presionando el botón que dice modificar.
- Selecciona la carga de trabajo para desarrollo de escritorio con C++ (la que está marcada y encerrada en un cuadro negro en la imagen de a continuación):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Seleccionar los siguientes dos componentes:

  ```
   1. Windows 10 SDK
   2. MSVC V140 VS C++ Build Tools para 'la arquitectura de tu CPU'
  ```

La primera es una dependencia de la segunda, la segunda son las herramienta de compilación de C++. Después de eso, podrías instalar el paquete (en teoría).

Este error no solo se presenta al instalar paquetes de Python que lo requieran también para instalar el compilador de Rust y antes el de C#. Esto último ya no es necesario con [dotnet](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/).

**En caso de que no funcione lo anterior:**

Puedes hacer los mismo pasos, instalar los mismos componentes, pero con las [Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/visual-cpp-build-tools/). Estas se pueden modificar de la misma manera que Visual Studio instalando el componente VS C++ 14.0.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para instalar chatterbot solo deberias instalar python (veo que lo tienes) y ejecutar:

```
pip install chatterbot
```

(No puedo comentar todavia) Necesito más detalles de los pasos que has ejecutado.

Prueba con :

```
pip install chatterbot --user
```

para que lo instale solo al usuario actual.

Answer (score 0):

prueba de esta manera que a mi me funciono en win 10 esta fue la versión que pude instalar

```
(pip install chatterbot==1.0.4)
```